# Unable to parse knockout JSON in PHP $_get

Tags: php, jquery, knockout.js, json

Here is my JavaScript code

```
    var student = student || {};            

    student.viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.courseCode = ko.observable("");

        self.courses = ko.observableArray([
            { "code": "MTH101", "title": "General Mathematics I" },
            { "code": "CHM101", "title": "Introductory Chemistry I" },
            { "code": "PHY101", "title": "General Physics I" },
            { "code": "BIO101", "title": "Introduction to Biology" }
        ]);

        self.removeCourse = function () { self.courses.remove(this); };
        self.addCourse = function (data) {
            self.courses.push({ code: data, title: "A new Course added " + new Date() });
            $('#courseModal').modal('hide');
        };

        self.save = function() {        
            $.ajax("test.php", {
                data: ko.toJSON({ courses: self.courses }),
                type: "get", contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(result) { alert(result) }
            });
        };
    };

    student.VM = new student.viewModel();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(student.VM);
    });
```

**How do I read the data sent in PHP?** `json_decode()` only accepts strings and when I also use `htmlspecialchars($_GET["courses"])` I get the error *undefined index courses.* I just want to tell the user the number of courses that was sent to the server.

If it helps, I am testing on localhost using wamp

Comment: How about adding `var_dump($_GET);` into your test.php script and checking what's there in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
data: {courses : ko.toJSON(self.courses)},
```

Also, a POST request would be better than a GET, if you're sending JSON.